# Running a testcase in localhost url of an application that has been containerised

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, connection, localhost

I have a java application that I am running inside a docker container. I have created a docker-compose file, there are other services as well to it (dynamo, kafka etc).
I have exposed port 8085 for the java application.

Now when I am connecting to localhost from curl (outside the container), I am getting proper data from DB like i have inserted but the behaviour of same container changes if I am running testcases that uses localhost:8085 as base URL.

I am not sure why there is two different behaviour for same instance that is up and running.

Comment: `localhost` is incredibly context-sensitive.  Right now I think it's my laptop; your application container, your database container, and curl from outside a container all believe it's a different thing.  Can you provide a [mcve] showing what you're trying to call as "localhost", from where, and what result you're getting?

Comment: I've fixed that issue. So there are multiple containers in a shared network started using docker compose. Two of the containers are for my java application and dynamodb. Adding `extra_hosts` in application's details helped with connection.

Now I'm trying to do a localhost call (since my java application is now started) and it uses the mentioned dynamodb at the port. But data is not coming as expected even when I can access it from within the _application container_.